# How add back button into navigation bar?

Tags: uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I have code in which i have hide default navigation back button. now i want to add new button at that place. and when press button then open main view or first screen of project. how i do that?

Comment: If u think that it is similar to any question then tell me how it? I think it differ because i check all and then i ask. Because they not work for me.

Comment: is yar application a navigation based app???

Comment: yes my apps is navigation based app.

Comment: you can go for leftBarButtonItem then.

Comment: i use this code but not show button on uibar.UIButton *localFlipIndicator=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,30,30)];
 
    self.flipIndicatorButton=localFlipIndicator;
 
    [localFlipIndicator release];
    UIBarButtonItem *flipButtonBarItem;
    flipButtonBarItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:flipIndicatorButton];
 
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:flipButtonBarItem animated:YES];
    [flipButtonBarItem release];
 [flipIndicatorButton addTarget:self action:@selector(Back:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpInside   )];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
UIBarButtonItem *customItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:bttnImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(Back:)];
[self.navigationController setHidesBackButton:YES];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem: customItem];
[customItem release];
```

Hope it will work for you...

Comment: Yes it working for me. Can u tell me how change title of back button which is automatically create by navigation controller?

Comment: thats fine. Well one simple way to do that is setting the title of the current viewControleler(self.title = @"Title")as you wise.This will automatically changed the back button's title of next viewController.Do that just before navigation if u want to hide the actual one.little tricky. 

And the second way

self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =
  [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Custom Title"
            style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
           target:nil
           action:nil] autorelease];